# Application freezes on call to SetLength

Tags: delphi

This question might or might not solve my problem - but I hope to learn how Delphi/Windows can behave in a way which can cause this.

I have an application which uses a 3rd party component to load an Outlook .msg file.

In some cases (specific mails) the application freezes when calling SetLength (inside of the component, I have the source code). 
This happens sometimes when setLength is called inside of a procedure which loads the properties from the file (stream). It happens the exact same place on the same mail - and can be reproduced every time.

Obviously the component does a lot of stuff and it is probably a sideeffect of some of this. However, the mails contains confidential data which I cannot send to the developer of the 3rd party component, so I cannot send it to him to debug it.

The program is running under windows XP on a domain.
The curious thing is that it only happens when the user running the program is not set to be administrator on the local machine.

```
ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  WriteStorageToStream(SubStorage, ms);
  ApplyValue(ms, ms.Size)
finally
  ms.Free;
end;

procedure ApplyValue(Stream: TStream; brLen: Integer);
var
  s: AnsiString;
begin
  SetLength(s, brLen);          // this freezes it all. brLen=3512
  FillChar(s[1], brLen, #0);
  Stream.Read(s[1], brLen);
  Value := s;
end;
```

What WriteStorageToStream does exactly is unknown to me, but since we are not manipulating the stream and brLen has an integer value, I assume it's irrelevant.

Comment: Have author to sign NDA, pay him for that. Works better than secrecy.

Comment: So the original developer is telling you that he/she can't debug it without seeing the .msg file, and you expect us to figure it out for you with absolutely no info? You haven't given us much to go on here. Without source to `WriteStorageToStream`, it's hard to tell what might be a problem,  no idea what `ms` contains when passed to `ApplyValue`, etc. (The one thing I did see is `ms.Position` isn't set to 0 after `WriteStorageToStream` and before `ApplyValue`; it may in fact be the `Stream.Read` that's hanging because it's at the end of the stream when the read method is called.)

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: Delphi 2009.

I haven't spoken to the original developer about it, so he haven't said anything. I will talk to him/switch to another component if that is required.

The question is mostly about understanding how Delphi/Windows can behave like that. Especially since it's reproducable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it was simple memory overwrite, causing a failure of the memory manager when the SetLength is called which then tries to use the memory management structures. The problem is in WriteStorageToStream(SubStorage, ms);

To find it, use the FastMM debug version with the memory overwrite detection options turned on.

Comment: Thanks, it appears the component does mess up the memory and I learned what I wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no reason SetLength would freeze on a AnsiString that's only 3512 characters long. How are you sure that it's freezing there and not somewhere earlier (like in WriteStorageToSteam)?  Presumably you're stepping through this in the debugger.  Does the CPU spike to 100% on that process thread when it's frozen? The fact that it freezes only on certain emails indicates to me that something in the contents of those emails is causing the freeze.  The call to SetLength has nothing to do with the contents; it only cares about the length.

Comment: My thought too, code and dcu not matvhing up, so the debugger says the errir is on a different line. Even less likeley to be this if it doesn't do when local admin. I'd be deleing all my object files and rebuilding if I got something like this.

Comment: I haven't stepped thru, because I'm a local admin on the machine I have Delphi installed on. I've used the brilliant debugging method of showmessages.
    `showmessage('1');`
    `SetLength(s, brLen);`
    `showmessage('2');  <-- never shown`

The CPU does ~nothing.
I'm sure that it has something to do with the emails - this code is running thru the properties of an outlook email and the place where it freezes is the part where it's trying to read a binary property into the 'value' variable.

Comment: Create a user on the machine that is just a standard user. Then use the debugger.

Comment: @Hald: more likely it is `ShowMessage()` itself that is freezing, and not `SetLength()`.  Is this code being called in a worker thread, by chance?  `ShowMessage()` is not thread-safe.  It displays a custom `TForm`, and thus must NEVER be called from outside the context of the main thread.  If you want to display a thread-safe message box, use the Win32 API `MessageBox()` function directly (not the `TApplication.MessageBox()` method, which is not thread-safe, either).

Comment: I just tried setting up remote debugging, so I could step thru it.

It does halt on the SetLength(s, brLen) line - not on the showMessage.
Also, it is not running from inside of a thread.